# Python: Subtract a float from a function (in order to call scipy.newton())

Tags: python, function, syntax, scipy

I want to call `scipy.newton(f, x0, df)`.

I have `f` defined as

```
def f(x):
    resf = x**2
    return resf
```

and `df` as

```
def df(x):
    df = 2*x
    return df
```

I call `newton` like this

```
x0 = 1.0    
y0 = 6.0
root = newton(f-y0, x0, df)
```

Of course I'm getting an error, because I try to subtract a `float`from a `function`.

How do I have to define the function `f` and call `newton` to find the root of `f-y0`.

What is the syntax, what are the input arguments?

The following doesn't work:

```
 def f(x, y0):
    resf = x**2-y0
    return resf
```

because then I don't know how to call `newton`.

Comment: where is x coming from?

Comment: I can't tell you. When I call "newton" with f, without the x argument, it seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass an anonymous function like this:

```py
root = newton(lambda x: f(x)-y0, x0, df)
```

---

Using a nested function is possible as well:

```
def difference(x):
    return f(x) - y0

root = newton(difference, x0, df)
```

Comment: (+1) It might be worth mentioning that care must be taken to ensure that this new function has the same first derivative as the original function (which in this example it does).

Comment: @Falko: For your case II, it doesn't know where the y0 comes from unless I pass it as an argument to difference(x, y0). But then x is undefined when I call newton(difference(x, y0), x0, df)

Comment: @NPE: y0 is a constant, but in general you're right of course.

Comment: ```y0``` needs to get defined *before* defining ```difference```. Then it is known within the function.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option `args=` you can use in `scipy.optimize.newton` to supply additional parameters. Then the `df` has to be modified in order to accept that additional parameter as well, which can be simply done by adding `*args, **kwargs`.

Using `functools.partial` will be associated with 12% additional run time.

```
In [26]:
import functools
import scipy.optimize as so

def f(x, y0):
    resf = x**2-y0
    return resf
def df(x, *args, **kwargs):
    df = 2*x
    return df
x0 = 1.0    
y0 = 6.0
so.newton(f, x0, args=(y0,), fprime=df)

Out[26]:
2.449489742783178

In [27]:
%timeit so.newton(f, x0, args=(y0,), fprime=df)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.54 µs per loop

In [28]:
%timeit so.newton(functools.partial(f, y0=y0), x0, df)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.4 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the two-argument version of `f()` with [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
def f(x, y0):
    resf = x**2-y0
    return resf

x0 = 1.0    
y0 = 6.0
root = scipy.optimize.newton(functools.partial(f, y0=y0), x0, df)
```

I have a slight preference for this method over wrapping the one-argument version of `f()` since it's easier to see that `df()` is the correct derivative w.r.t. `x`.

Comment: There is always the `args=` option that you can use to pass additional parameters.